# iPhone - Calendar Like Paging on Table View Header

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, calendar, paging

Does anyone know a good example for Paging the views using dates... Calendar Like Paging on the Table View Header? I know it can be done a lot of time management, financial management apps have it. I just need to go on a right direction before cooking something of my own.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://github.com/klazuka/Kal